# Unwanted property change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Using XCode 6.0.1 running on Yosemite. I have a property that gets set to a value the user types into a text box e.g. "090".

```
//
//  AppController.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "ORSSerialPort.h"
#import "ORSSerialPortManager.h"

@class ORSSerialPortManager;

#if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED <= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7)
  @protocol NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate <NSObject>
@end
#endif

@interface AppController : NSObject <ORSSerialPortDelegate,NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *hdgVal;

- (void)printHdg;
@end
```

Later, I need the integer value for a comparison. At the line tagged "CRASH HERE", when I click on hdgVal, the bubble says "class name=_NSArrayI". Clicking on the eyeball, says the value is 10,10,0.

```
//
//  AppController.m
//


#import "AppController.h"
@implementation AppController

@synthesize hdgVal;

- (void)startTimer
{
    hdgTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6 
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(printHdg)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
}

- (void)printHdg
{
    NSInteger currH = [labelCurrHdg integerValue];
    NSInteger wantedH = [hdgVal integerValue];  <== CRASH HERE
    NSData *dataToSend;
    NSString *str;
    if (currH > wantedH - 3 && currH  < wantedH + 3) {
        [hdgTimer invalidate];
        hdgTimer = nil;
        [labelCurrHdg setStringValue:hdgVal];
        [labelCurrHdg needsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"Stopping timer");
        return;
    }
```

Code that fills hdgVal

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender
{

NSString *sendString = @"";
NSString *tmpStr;
NSString *tmpVal;
NSData *dataToSend;
int i;
int c;
char j;
if([sender tag] ==1)
{
    NSButton *btn=(NSButton *)sender;
  [btn setTitle:([btn.title isEqualToString:@"LP"] ? @"SP" : @"LP")];
    i = [inputTextField intValue];
    if(i < 181)
    {
        i = i + 180;
    }
    else if (i > 180)
    {
        i = i - 180;
    }
    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
    [numberFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:3];
    NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    tmpStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
    [numberFormatter release];
    [inputTextField setStringValue:tmpStr];
    hdgVal = tmpStr;
}
else if([sender tag] == 0)
{
    [buttonLP setTitle:@"LP"];
    tmpStr = [inputTextField stringValue];
    while([tmpStr length] < 3)
    {
      tmpStr = [@"0" stringByAppendingString:tmpStr];
    }
    [inputTextField setStringValue:tmpStr];
    hdgVal = tmpStr;
}
else if([sender tag] ==3)
{
    NSButton *btn=(NSButton *)sender;
  [btn setTitle:([btn.title isEqualToString:@"LP"] ? @"SP" : @"LP")];

    i = [inputTextField2 intValue];
    if(i < 181)
    {
        i = i + 180;
    }
    else if (i > 180)
    {
        i = i - 180;
    }
    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
    [numberFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:3];
    NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    tmpStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
    [numberFormatter release];
    [inputTextField2 setStringValue:tmpStr];
    hdgVal = tmpStr;
}
else if([sender tag] == 2)
{
    [buttonLP2 setTitle:@"LP"];
    tmpStr = [inputTextField2 stringValue];
    while([tmpStr length] < 3)
    {
      tmpStr = [@"0" stringByAppendingString:tmpStr];
    }
    [inputTextField2 setStringValue:tmpStr];
    hdgVal = tmpStr;
}
switch(rotorSelected)
{
    case 1:    //Alfaspid and Yaesu
    case 7:
        sendString = @"M";
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:(hdgVal)];
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"];
        dataToSend = [sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        break;
    case 2:    //DCU
        sendString = @"AP1";
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:(hdgVal)];
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:@";AM1;"];
        NSLog(@"SendString = %@", sendString);
        dataToSend = [sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        if (!hdgTimer)
        {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
            [self startTimer];
        }
        break;
    case 3: //Prosistel A B C
        c = 2;
        j = (char)c;
        tmpVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", j];
        dataToSend = [tmpVal dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];

        tmpStr = [inputTextField stringValue];
        for (i = 0 ; i < [tmpStr length]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Iteration: %d", i);
            tmpVal = [tmpStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            c = [tmpVal intValue];
            j = (char)c;
            tmpVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", j];
            dataToSend = [tmpVal dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        }
        c = 13;
        j = (char)c;
        dataToSend = [tmpVal dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        break;
    case 4: //Prosistel CBOX/D
        //char c = 0x02; dataToSend = [NSData dataWithBytes:&c length:1]
        j = 0x02;
        dataToSend = [NSData dataWithBytes:&j length:1];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        tmpStr = @"AG";
        tmpStr = [tmpStr stringByAppendingString:(hdgVal)];
        dataToSend = [tmpStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        j = 0x0d;
        dataToSend = [NSData dataWithBytes:&j length:1];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        break;
    case 5: //RC-2800PX
        sendString = @"A#";
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:(hdgVal)];
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:@"\r"];
        dataToSend = [sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        break;
    case 6: //SARTEK
        sendString = @"P";
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:(hdgVal)];
        sendString = [sendString stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"];
        dataToSend = [sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: You setup `hgdVal` to be a string but it actually contains an array. Where's your code that sets the value for the `hdgVal` property?

Comment: I don't get why it changes to an array. Code added above to show how it's filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a simple memory management issue. Since you are using MRC (why aren't you using ARC?), you need to ensure that the value you assign to the `hdgVal` ivar is properly retained.

The simplest solution (besides using ARC) is to replace every direct use of the `hdgVal` ivar with a reference to the `hdgVal` property.

Change:

```
hdgVal = tmpStr; // direct ivar access, no retain called
```

to:

```
self.hdgVal = tmpStr; // use the property, value retained
```

The code you have is assigning an autoreleased string directly to the ivar. Once the original string is released, your ivar points to garbage and later some other arbitrary value. In the case you posted, an `NSArray` just happened to be using that memory.

Comment: @maddy I'm not using ARC because a third party serial port library can't use it.

Comment: That's not a valid reason. You can still use ARC in your project even if some files don't.

Comment: @maddy I was wrong, the serial port library actually requires ARC, and in fact it's turned on. I'm surprised XCode didn't complain about the declaration of hdgVal (I assume that's why you asked about ARC). I didn't know you could mix.